# Campagnolo rear mech with Sram groupset

Tags: road-bike, mechanical, groupsets

Is it possible to install a Campagnolo Record 11 speed mechanical rear derailleur on a bike that is otherwise equipped with a Sram Force 11 speed groupset?

Has anyone ever used a similar setup and if so, how did it shift?  Were there any problems in mixing the two brands?

Comment: The obvious question is *why*?

Comment: @Batman Because this is a Q&A site and I have a question. I don't believe my motivation for doing this has any bearing on the answer whatsoever. Let's say I have a spare record mech and I want to experiment...

Answer (score 1):

No. it won't shift correctly - SRAM must be used with appropriate SRAM levers, Shimano with compatible Shimano levers, Campagnolo with compatible Campagnolo levers.
Each manufacturer has their own ratio for cable recovery to derailleur movement, each company has their own strategy for coping with the fact that the angular movement of the chain sprocket-to-sprocket across the range of the cassette has to vary slightly.
Shimano and SRAM manage the latter mostly in the lever, Campagnolo split the management across the lever and the cassette spacing, which contrary to most internet chatter is not the same as Shimano / SRAM and nor is it constant.

Comment: Why does the movement of the chain have to vary? Also, can you expand on how shimano/sram manage it in the level campy in the cassette? I've seen campy cassettes used with shimano groups.

Comment: @ebrohman Cassettes are interchangeable in *some* configurations. I used to have a bike with a 9-speed Sram cassette and the rest of the drivetrain was 9-speed Campy - and that worked great. I don't think you can do that with 11 speed systems. And you were originally asking about using a Campy derailleur with Sram shifters - that's something totally different. Graeme's right, it won't work.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak that's good to know. I'd like to know a bit more information from Graeme as I mentioned in a comment on this answer. If you can provide that info in an answer I'll gladly accept it!